# How to Pop all element in Stack using function

Tags: c#, stack

Hi i want to empty the full Stack by function not one by one i want to use a loop in a function which delete/Pop all the stack element you can see my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
public class SamplesStack
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        // Creates and initializes a new Stack.
        Stack myStack = new Stack();
        myStack.Push("Hello");
        myStack.Push("World");
        myStack.Push("!");


        // Displays the properties and values of the Stack.
       // Console.WriteLine("myStack");
        Console.WriteLine("\tCount:    {0}", myStack.Count);
        Console.Write("\tValues:");
        PrintValues(myStack);
       object pt = myStack.Pop();
        Console.WriteLine("\tCount:    {0}", myStack.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void PrintValues(IEnumerable myCollection)
    {
        foreach (Object obj in myCollection)
            Console.Write("    {0}", obj);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    public static void emptyStack(Stack empty)
    {
     what to do here

    }
```

Comment: Use [Stack.Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack.clear?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Take a look at this question, it provides a path to answer your own question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252917/fastest-way-to-iterate-over-a-stack-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different options. Here are a couple:

1. The easy option is one line of code mentioned in the comments: `myStack.Clear();` ([Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack.clear?view=netframework-4.8)).
2. Loop through the stack and pop until it's empty:

```
while(myStack.Count > 0) 
{ 
   myStack.Pop();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, it works but can you tell me how i do this using a function let say a function EmptyStack{}

Comment: Put that code in your method `public static void emptyStack(Stack myStack)` and then call the method by simply passing your stack to the method: `emptyStack(myStack)`. (You may want to change method Stack variable name so they're not both "myStack")

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer to my Question i have tried different Things so i have done this by this function

```
public static void PopStack(Stack stObj)
    {
        foreach (var st in stObj.ToArray())
        {
            var obj= stObj.Pop();
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.WriteLine(obj);

        }

        Console.WriteLine("\tCount:    {0}", stObj.Count);

    }
```

Comment: What about `stObj.Clear();` ? Why do you need to define your own method?